# Why does my access form lose focus

Tags: forms, ms-access, lost-focus

I have a Microsoft Access form which I use for entering client information:

First name
Last name
etc..

My problem is when I tab away from the Access Form to view the information which needs to be entered, the focus is lost in access.  I need to click the form with the mouse to regain the focus.

This is very annoying!

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know, the focus of an access object is lost when you clic anything outside the object... that includes forms.

I can suggest you two ways of tacling this:

1. Use a control (combo box or list box) inside your form, so you can view the data you need.
2. Use a "pop up" form: you can create a form with the data you need, and a button inside your main form that opens this "pop up" form. You can specify in VBA if you want your form to open as a pop-up... if I remeber correctly, is something like this:

   ```
   ...
   docmd.openform("frmYourForm",,,acDialog)
   ...
   ```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Check access help for more info about the `openform` method